# Cannot Resize the Ubuntu Partition Dual Boot - Gparted says read only - Partition Wizard Missing the Resize Option on That Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to swing about 50GB from the Ubuntu Partition to the Windows 10 partition on a dual boot. The computer has only 2 primary partitions. Fast Boot is missing from the options in windows (and windows was recently updated), but I did turn it off by the Powershell. I tried 2 different partition software on windows and both are blocking any resize option for the Ubuntu partition.

I haven't yet tried Gparted Live with the OS on a USB. I was hoping to fix the read only problem through settings, but so far nothing is working.

If anyone might know the best steps to take I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you booted onto the Linux partition you are trying to move?

Comment: I have tried from the linux and windows side, each time restart or shutdown - no hibernation

Comment: I believe running Gparted live is the only way to accomplish your objective.  Take great care if either of those two operating systems are production devices.  Backup! :)

Comment: Thanks I will do that :)

Answer (score 0):

My Lenovo partitions are adjusted and working now, so thank you for the assistance

The method to fix was

1. Disable fast boot in the settings
2. Disable secure boot in BIOS
3. Make a bootable USB with Gparted Live and adjust the BIOS to enable USB boot
4. With Gparted reduce the size of the Ubuntu partition, leaving free disk space, then reboot
5. Test Linux was working fine
6. Boot to Windows and use Mini Tool Partition Wizard to turn the unallocated space to a Windows NTFS partition